# Removing file which doesn't have any permissions and attributes

Tags: linux, files

I have a file on my external hard disk named ._Icon^M.I ended up with this after using my hard disk on old Mac platform machine.
I want to delete this file but unable to.

For the command 'ls -al' it shows as

```
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 8192 Mar 6 19:53 ..
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?           ? ._Icon?
```

Seeing this I tried to add ownership (using chown) and modify the permissions(using chmod) but the commands are not recognising ._Icon as file or a directory.

I tried deleting the file using the command -

```
find . -name '._*' -exec rm '{}' ';'
```

rm is not able to remove as it is not interpreting it as a file or a directory
The console after running the above command is

```
rm: cannot remove './._Icon\r': No such file or directory
```

How do I delete such a file?

Comment: Are you able to move via mv command? If so, do you take the ownership so that you can delete it?

Comment: @LaurentC. I tried that but its not working either.
Edit: It isn't recognising it as a file or a directory

Comment: What if you do `rm ._Icon\?` ??

Comment: @fedorqui : I had tried that but it is not recognised as either a file or directory

Comment: Strange... I created a file with that exact name `._Icom?` and worked to me. Are you trying to remove from its dir?

Comment: @fedorqui : What are the permission flags on the file you created ?

Comment: @fedorqui the file is not `._Icom?` but `._Icom\r` and it is a filesystem problem,  not a regular file as you can see from the `ls -l` output. You won't be able to replicate this unless you use your disk on a mac.

Comment: You've got a directory entry that points to an unallocated inode, you'll want to run a fsck.

Comment: You can reproduce by doing `set_inode_field path/to/file links_count 0` in `debugfs`. `fsck` would say: `Entry 'file' in /path/to (2) has deleted/unused inode 12.  Clear<y>?`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks. I ran fsck first. Then the perl script suggested by terdon. It worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things you can try:

- Try to complete the file using tab autocompletion. For example

  ```
  rm .[TAB]
  ```
- Move all other files from this directory somewhere else and then delete the directory. That should get rid of the file.
- Move all other files and just run (assuming GNU `find`) this:

  ```
  find . -type f -delete
  ```
- Delete all files in the directory that start with a  dot:

  ```
  rm -r .*
  ```
- Get the file's inode and delete it using that. `ls -i` *should* show you the inode. Alternatively, run

  ```
  find . -printf "%i %f\n"
  ```

  Once you have the inode, try deleting using `find` again:

  ```
  find . -inum XXX -delete
  ```
- Try this Perl script. Change `dirname` for the name of the directory containing the file and run this from the parent directory. So, if your file is `~/foo/file` run this in `~/` and change `dirname` to `foo`.

  ```
  perl  -e 'use File::Path qw(remove_tree); remove_tree("dirname")'
  ```

Comment: I tried but its not working. For the first method you mentioned, after autocompletion it is displayed as "rm ._Icon^M" but it isn't working. Also I have moved all files from the directory and tried using find with -delete option but its not working for me.

Comment: @ganesh737 doesn't deleting the directory itself work? Also try `rm -r .*`

Comment: I tried that as "rm -R directory" but it isn't working.

Comment: @ganesh737 really? What error message? And `rm .*`? How about `mv` the directory somewhere else? Does that work?

Comment: for `rm .*`, i'm getting the same output on console but i am able to move the directory.

Comment: @ganesh737 what error do you get if your try `rm -r directory`?

Comment: i moved the folder to directory 'an' and then tried - `rm -r an` for the console message is `rm: cannot remove 'an/._Icon\r': No such file or directory`

Comment: @ganesh737 try `rm -rf an/` and also see updated answer for some more possibilities.

Comment: the perl script worked after running fsck... Thank you so much!!!

Comment: wait, is `rm -r .*` really safe? Won't that try to recurse into `..`?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you cannot remove it because of the CR (`\r`) character. You can try with the following:

```
echo -ne "._Icon\r" | xargs rm
```

And see if it removes it.

Comment: I tried it but i'm still getting the same output on console from rm command

Comment: You don't want the `-0` that makes `xarg` expect null separated strings and that's not what you are passing it.

Answer (score 0):

When I had similar problems I was able to delete files by inode

```
ls -li
```

first column is inode

To delete it

```
find . -inum num_inode | xargs rm
```

Comment: Here, the `????` indicate that the `lstat` fails, so `ls -li` won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Such symptoms are normally due to not being able to give the correct file name to `rm(1)`. One solution is doing something like, in this case:

```
rm -i .*
```

(i.e., ask for removal of all files called `.*`, but ask for each one).

To find out what the exact name is, `ls -ba` (give C escapes for "strange" characters, list all files) might help. There are other (GNU) ls flags that might be of use.